# How to save 2 inputs to different ModelAttributes?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a Person class and a ModelAttribute "nameList", which gets existing people name list from database:

```
@ModelAttribute("nameList")
public List<String> getNames() {
    return databaseModel.getNamesList();
}
```

In jsp I have a form, where I want to have 2 dropdown lists with names to select:

```
    <f:form class="form-inline" action="setRelative" modelAttribute="person1"
        modelAttribute="person2" >

        <label>Person:</label>
        <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="name" items="${nameList}"
            multiple="false">
        </f:select>
        <f:errors path="name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>

        <f:label path="name">Relative:</f:label>
        <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="name" items="${nameList}"
            multiple="false">
        </f:select>
        <f:errors path="name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>

        <label>Person's Relation to Relative:</label>           
        <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="relations"
            items="${relationList}" multiple="false">

        </f:select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Set
            relative</button>

    </f:form>
```

I have used "modelAttribute" twice in the form and it gives the following error: **"Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element"**. But without it I cannot have different names, selected from the list. This is the result of the form with using ModelAttribute once:  [image]

I can of course use simple input field and then use it in controller, but is there a way to deal with multiple ModelAttributes at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with model attribute, but with the `path='name'` being used twice.

Spring cannot understand which value to use for the `name` path, you should either change it to something like `path='name1'` and `path='name2'` (and make corresponding changes to your model) or if you use names as an array or list name it like `path='name[0]'` and `path='name[1]'`

I am not sure how you use the name without seeing the code for the controller, but the main idea is that problem lies not within model attribute but within the same path being used twice

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I use 'name1' and 'name2', if both 'person1' and 'person2' relate to the same class 'Person' with attribute 'name'?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice `person1` and `person2` in the form declaration, you cannot duplicate attributes in the form declaration, you have to create separate form for each person

Comment: But there should be a way to work on 2 objects of the same class in the form, right? It seems stupid, if there is not, because it is very common to compare 2 objects of the same class.